# How can I split data in javascript having | symbol?

Tags: javascript

I have data like

```
var result = 'Zika NAA, Blood|Zika NAA, Urine'
```

My requirement is

```
var result = Zika NAA, Blood
             Zika NAA, Urine
```

`|` symbol shouldn't be there. How to achieve in javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.write('Zika NAA, Blood|Zika NAA, Urine'.split('|').join('<br>'));
```

Comment: comma should not be there after "Zika NAA, Blood" and "Zika NAA, Urine" should be in new line.

Comment: @SoumyaBehera Like this?

Comment: yeah correct. thank you...

Answer (score 1):

```js
var result = 'Zika NAA, Blood|Zika NAA, Urine'.replace('|', ' ');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This will not split the data - merely space it further apart - @Alexander Elgin has the correct answer IMO

Comment: Zika NAA, Urine sud be in new line.

Comment: Being on a newline in the js is not required - its only better for readability - not functionality - the reason why I up-voted and praised  @Alexander Elgin is that his answer splits the one string into an array that has two items - this can be iterated over and appended to a ul or a table or however you are rendering it in the DOM (or if it was passed to a variable and then iterated over (instead of just console logging the items) it would.)  This answer cannot do that without itself being split at the newly introduced space.